# Java bad operand types for binary operator '||'

Tags: java

Есть код в контроллере (Spring MVC)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String books(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {
    if (request.getParameter("name") || request.getParameter("publishing_house") || request.getParameter("the_year_of_publishing")) {
        final List<Book> books = bookService.booksBySearch();
    } else {
        final List<Book> books = bookService.getAll();
    }
    model.addAttribute("books", books);
    logger.debug("running in BookController.java -> books()");
    logger.info(JSON.toJSON(request.getRequestURI()));
    logger.info(JSON.toJSON(books));
    return "/book/list.jsp";
}
```

В итоге при компиляции получаю ошибку:

> [ERROR] /C:/Users/Tim/eclipse-workspace/springMVC-mybatis-postgresql-fbcda0e11b1addcac43be8813e16b8b703022591/src/main/java/com/core/newbie/controller/BookController.java:[53,42] bad operand types for binary operator '||'
>     first type:  java.lang.String
>     second type: java.lang.String

Почему и как выправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чего вы ожидаете от этого `request.getParameter("name") || request.getParameter("publishing_house")`?

[`getParameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) строку возвращает. Может вы хотели на `null` проверять?

```
if (request.getParameter("name") != null || request.getParameter("publishing_house") != null || request.getParameter("the_year_of_publishing") != null )
```

Но даже так ваш код не будет компилиться, т.к. у вас `books` не определена вне скопа ваших `if`'ов, и компилятор выдаст ошибку на этой строке `model.addAttribute("books", books);`.

Весь код тогда будет таким:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String books(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {
    List<Book> books;
    if (request.getParameter("name") != null || request.getParameter("publishing_house") != null || request.getParameter("the_year_of_publishing") != null) {
        books = bookService.booksBySearch();
    } else {
        books = bookService.getAll();
    }
    model.addAttribute("books", books);
    logger.debug("running in BookController.java -> books()");
    logger.info(JSON.toJSON(request.getRequestURI()));
    logger.info(JSON.toJSON(books));
    return "/book/list.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: @TimurMusharapov рад был помочь ^_^